# Why does Ruby's 14.5.round() does a better job (giving 15) than "%.0f" % 14.5 (giving 14)

Tags: ruby, floating-point

Why does `round()` do a better job than the `printf` type of string formatting?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "%.0f" % 14.5
 => "14" 

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > "%.0f" % 14.5000001
 => "15" 

ruby-1.9.2-p0 > 14.5.round
 => 15
```

Comment: Eeemmm... because... because. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf  and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer - a lot of stuff to read.

Comment: Equivalent to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken) even though it's in another language.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm It's not equivalent because it's trying to get at the difference between `"%.0f" % 14.5` and `14.5.round.to_s` (e.g. what are the specific nuance rules of %f?)

Answer (score 3):

Just because you've learned in school that `.5` is always rounded up does not mean that's the only correct way to do it. There are quite a number of different [rounding modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Rounding_modes); what you're looking at is most likely "round to even", which rounds `.5` towards the even integer; this has the advantage of not producing an overall upwards bias like always rounding up does.

High-quality math libraries like [Ruby Flt](http://flt.rubyforge.org/) generally provide a way to explicitly choose the rounding mode.

Answer (score 1):

"Better job"?  No, not if you care about things averaging out.  Hence, round towards even.

Comment: round towards even?  what do you mean?  rounding only to 14 and then to 16 next?

Comment: That's exactly what he means. If you always round x.5 up, you end up with a small, but statistically significant bias where a total or average is overstated. Rounding x.5 to the nearest even number counters the bias effect.